# Efficient way to replace values in a dataframe with extracted content from an object?

Tags: r

I have a dataframe like this:

```
Hours                 work_place         overtime   
More than 48 hours    Farm          Overtime paid                 
Less than 48 horas    Factory       Overtime paid 
More than 48 hours    Office        Overtime paid                
Less than 48 horas    Farm          Overtime not paid 
More than 48 hours    Factory       Overtime paid                
Less than 48 horas    Office        Overtime paid
```

In a separate process I create several objects. process$object1 looks like this:

process$object1

```
                        Dim1   Dim2   Dim3
 More than 48 hours       0.05  0.33  0.96
 Less than 48 horas      -0.02 -0.16 -0.47
 Farm                     0.14  1.51  0.29
 Factory                 -0.13  0.15  1.03
 Office                   0.01  2.05 -0.47
 Home                     0.00 -0.19 -0.14
 Overtime paid            0.03  0.04 -0.09
 Overtime not paid       -0.26 -0.32  0.76
```

I would like to replace the values in the original dataframe, with the values in column 1 (Dim1) of process$object1, so I end up with this...

```
  Hours2    work_place2  overtime2   
  0.05     0.14          0.03                 
 -0.02     -0.13         0.03
  0.05     0.01          0.03                
 -0.02     0.14         -0.26 
  0.05     -0.13         0.03                
 -0.02    0.01          0.03
```

Since the original dataframe is quite big, I'd like to do this using some kind of function in R. Any help is much appreciated.

**Data** in `dput()` format.

```
dat <-
structure(list(Hours = c("More than 48 hours", "Less than 48 horas", 
"More than 48 hours", "Less than 48 horas", "More than 48 hours", 
"Less than 48 horas"), work_place = c("Farm", "Factory", "Office", 
"Farm", "Factory", "Office"), overtime = c("Overtime paid", "Overtime paid", 
"Overtime paid", "Overtime not paid", "Overtime paid", "Overtime paid"
)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")

process <-
list(object1 = structure(list(Dim1 = c(0.05, -0.02, 0.14, -0.13, 
0.01, 0, 0.03, -0.26), Dim2 = c(0.33, -0.16, 1.51, 0.15, 2.05, 
-0.19, 0.04, -0.32), Dim3 = c(0.96, -0.47, 0.29, 1.03, -0.47, 
-0.14, -0.09, 0.76)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("More than 48 hours", 
"Less than 48 horas", "Farm", "Factory", "Office", "Home", "Overtime paid", 
"Overtime not paid")))

result <-
structure(list(Hours2 = c(0.05, -0.02, 0.05, -0.02, 0.05, -0.02
), work_place2 = c(0.14, -0.13, 0.01, 0.14, -0.13, 0.01), overtime2 = c(0.03, 
0.03, 0.03, -0.26, 0.03, 0.03)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Comment: Please use `dput(mydata)` to share your data.  Otherwise, everyone trying to answer your question first has to write code to read a copy/paste of your example data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
dat[c("Hours2", "work_place2", "overtime2")] <- lapply(
  X   = dat[c("Hours", "work_place", "overtime")],
  FUN = function(x) process[["object1"]][x, "Dim1"]
)
```

Because a `data.frame` is just a fancy list, you can assign new values with a new list of vectors. Because `process$object1` has names, you can use named subsetting inside `lapply` to do this.

Answer (score 0):

The following will do what you want. Note that the name of the first column of the result is `Hours` not `Hours2`.

```
fun <- function(x, DF, col){
    rn <- row.names(DF)
    inx <- match(x, rn)
    DF[inx, col]
}

res <- lapply(dat, fun, process$object1, 1)
res <- do.call(cbind.data.frame, res)
res
#  Hours work_place overtime
#1  0.05       0.14     0.03
#2 -0.02      -0.13     0.03
#3  0.05       0.01     0.03
#4 -0.02       0.14    -0.26
#5  0.05      -0.13     0.03
#6 -0.02       0.01     0.03
```

The function above could be a one-liner:

```
fun <- function(x, DF, col) DF[match(x, row.names(DF)), col]
```

But I find the multiline version more readable.